# How do I detect space separated numbers using regular expressions in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract 10 digit phone numbers from a text. The formats of the number are like this: `1234 567890` or `1234567890`.
I wrote following regex:

```
mask = re.compile('.[\d]{4}[\s]?[\d]{6}')
```

but this doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Comment: What error/unexpected behaviour do you get? For example, does the regular expression find anything, only some of the correct numbers, etc?

Comment: why the `.` at the beginning?

Comment: Also, why are you wrapping the `\d`s and `\s`s in brackets? It's unnecessary.

Comment: Didn't knew it can work without brackets. All the examples i saw (almost all on internet) did it this way so i just did. Thanks for correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `\d{4}\s?\d{6}`.

Why did you have that `.` at the beginning?

Comment: I wanted to ensure that there is a number at the start not a alphabet, which I see now was folly. Thanks

Comment: You could wrap the regex with `\b`s if you want to verify that it will not match something like this: "kIlLeRmAn1942 123456"